# Does Magento store something in PHP $_SESSION or PHP $_COOKIES while customer do the login & add items to cart.?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Because of some reason i have to check customer is logged in or cart having items. using only core PHP session or cookies.

Can anyone tell Does `Magento store something in PHP $_SESSION or PHP $_COOKIES while customer do the login & add items to cart?`

& if yes then how can we apply this check.

Comment: please don't post the same question over and over again

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to access Magento data from outside Magento? Do you know there is a REST API in Magento which you can use to get and write data from Magento storage?

Magento stores user data in the session yes. For example in the admin area there is `$_SESSION['user']` which contains a `Mage_Admin_Model_User` with all its data. On the frontend there's `$_SERVER['User']` (only the username). There does not seem to be anything about cart items in either frontend or backend session.

Do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` somewhere you can see it (for example in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php::_getProductCollection()`) and see for yourself what's in the variables!